# Right Click Detection for Firefox

Tags: javascript

Before beginning, I am not inquiring about stopping users from right-clicking. This is for right-click detection on a html5 canvas.

So currently, what I have is:

```
  function init() {
   var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasID');\
   if (canvas.getContext) {
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.font = '10px sans-serif';
    ctx.canvas.onmousedown=ctx.canvas.onclick=onMousePressed;
    ctx.canvas.onmouseup=ctx.canvas.onmouseout=onMouseReleased;
    ctx.canvas.onmousemove = onMouseMove;
   }
  }
```

And also:

```
      function onMouseMove(e) {
   if (mouseDown) {
    click2 = convertCoordsToTileCoords({
     x: e.offsetX || e.layerX - this.style.left,
     y: e.offsetY || e.layerY - this.style.top
    });
    var rightclick;
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    if (e.which) rightclick = (e.which == 3);
    else if (e.button) rightclick = (e.button == 2);
```

..etc
Where the variable 'rightclick' is a boolean, resulting in true if the person is right clicking.

Which browsers this works for:
Chrome

Opera, no, because of their mouse gestures and stuff.
IE, no, because of canvas.
But I cannot figure out why it will not work on Firefox.

As usual, if there is a better, more efficient, method of tackling this problem, it would be highly appreciated.

-Firstmate

Edit1: Provided more code.

Comment: You should probably accept an answer...

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using jQuery, there exists a [Right-click Plugin](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/05/jquery-right-click-plugin/) that makes this much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Testing this in Firefox 3.6.4/Mac worked as expected:

```
document.onclick = function(e) { 
    var rightclick;
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    if (e.which) rightclick = (e.which == 3);
    else if (e.button) rightclick = (e.button == 2);
    alter(rightclick);
}
```

Perhaps you're not attaching the click handler correctly?